# regex vba negative lookahead not working

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access, regex-lookarounds

First time question here, sorry if not as expected.

I'm working on an application on Access in which I need to classify some documents. I'm using regex to do so.

I thought it was working fine, but recently i've found out that some of the texts are matching when it shouldn't.

An example of the text that i'm testing is:

https://regex101.com/r/L1L2gg/2

Apparently, the negative lookahead is not working properly. On the Regex101 there are no matches (expected outcome), but when running the application, it finds a match, but i can't see why it does match.

IgnoreCase is True
MultiLine is True
Global is False

```
Pattern:(?=.*?\bacolho|julgo|julgando|julgar|reconheço\b)(?=.*?\bparcial|parcialmente\b).*^((?!vencidas).)*$

Text Match: "Reconheço de ofício, pois, apenas a prescrição parcial de eventuais parcelas atrasadas do benefício, restritamente àquelas vencidas antes do quinquênio anterior à propositura da ação."
```

If i remove the negative lookahead, on every regex tester, it finds the match, but when it's present, it doesn't match (which is what I expected). But on my application shouldn't it have the same outcome? Or there is something specific about regex on VBA that i'm missing?

Edit:
Just tested it on Excel, and worked as intended. Must be something broken on Access.

Comment: Wrap the `|` selection in parentheses.

Comment: The general placements of `\b` alone in that pattern suggest that it probably isn't working the way you think it's working. What exactly are you trying to do with this regex? The last part of your regex will probably cause it to never match anything because it's a `.*` followed by the beginning of string anchor point`^`.

Comment: The purpose of this code is to find a line that matches the pattern. In this case particularly, it shouldn't match, **but it does**. That's why i've put the negative lookahead for. Just tested the same pattern in Excel and it doesn't match, but on Access it does, still trying to figure what's wrong.
On other occasions, when there's no negative lookahead, it's working fine too.

Comment: On regexp101 it gives a timeout. That's why it doesn't match (which is not real. It may match with more time) Probably the regexp should be optimized. Can you describe with words what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Julio What i'm trying to do is sort some legal documents, so i can work faster with them. I don't know squat of AI to do the job, so I figured i could try Regex to do so. The objective is to get a document's (HTML) Text and run it some patterns to find. It should look up one or more words and exclude others (optional) in order to sort the document. The matching words are custom, since several other people use it. So, basically, i need a pattern that find some words, with alternatives, and also exclude others, if needed. In the example above, it sould find at least 2, excluding other.

Comment: I just tried using your sample data in Access VBA code [here](https://pastebin.com/aL7xm1VP) and it finds no matches. Please [edit] your question with a [mcve] showing a reproducible test case that works in Excel and fails in Access (including *how* you are using the regex in both Excel and Access).